# want to install new led lights but they have aluminum wires , can I join to copper wiring with Marrettes?

Tags: wiring, light-fixture, ceiling

Can I use ordinary wiring Marrettes to join aluminum and copper wire together to wire up led flush mount lights. Is there a product that will protect the joining of aluminum wiring and copper wiring ?

Comment: What makes your think they're aluminum?  That sound *highly improbable*...

Comment: What you think is aluminum may be copper wires that have been tinned.

Comment: Where "tinned" means "coated with solder, which is a silvery colored alloy, but not aluminum." It's pretty close to *inconceivable* that NEW fixtures (or LED fixtures, which are "new enough" even if used, in this context) would have aluminum wires.

Comment: Are these "aluminum" wires significantly easier to bend than copper wire of the same gauge? If so, it *might* be aluminum.

Comment: Very cheap Chinese components may also be made with aluminum wire.   But those would not be UL-listed, so we shouldn't be talking about them.

Comment: What do mean by "wiring *merits*"? Do you mean wire nuts?

Comment: Twist-on connectors are also known as wire nuts, wire connectors, cone connectors, or thimble connectors. One trade name for such connectors, Marrette, is derived from the name of their inventor (see History) and, in Canada, this type of connector is often referred to as a marrette regardless of the actual brand of the product.

Comment: If you really do have aluminum wire you should spread some anti-oxidant glop on the wires before joining them.  https://www.google.com/shopping/product/2635836455860049082?lsf=seller:6106742,store:15227900311339148420,lsfqd:0&prds=oid:10194941956922074530&q=solder+and+flux&hl=en&ei=DE5IYvOzBJuGtQam2pW4BQ&lsft=gclid:Cj0KCQjw6J-SBhCrARIsAH0yMZhtrXGbZoQzOBa1i8Gcu7flCxvIc6sYFZsmoTxVzlKfs_Lf1WLBm1oaAt0rEALw_wcB

Answer (score 2):

Although I doubt you have aluminum wiring in a new device (probably tinned copper).
You can join aluminum wire to copper wire with alumiconns. These are special wire nuts that have a special jell inside and these are 1 use only (alumiconns are usually purple or the 2 brands I have used are purple) for example the box I have on the shelf is ideal brand Twister AL/CU, these are listed for aluminum to copper wire connections. Regular wire nuts create a fire hazard with copper to aluminum connections so it can or needs to be done with alumiconns.
I would bet you have tinned stranded wire coming from the new fixture. If you take a knife and scrape the wires there will s probably copper under the tin. If copper under the tin you can just use a standard wire it that is the correct size for the wire.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same set up at my house. We have to use the purple alum-icon all the time as we have been going one room at a time to update all the electrical. This is a normal practice.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).